# How to index a text(large data) field using sunspot solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, indexing

In rails 4.0.2, I am using sunspot solr as a search engine. Here, there is one text field which contains large text(data) with special characters.

While running a reindex command, I am getting an error like `Backtrace: /home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:283:in 'adapt_response'...`

In model,

```
searchable do
  string   :cv_content
end
```

Using Gems are,

```
sunspot (2.1.1)
sunspot_rails (2.1.1)
sunspot_solr (2.1.1)
```

How can I solve reindex issue?

Full Error:

`Backtrace: /home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:283:in`adapt_response'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:190:in `execute'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:176:in`send_and_receive'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`block in instrument'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`instrument'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
(eval):2:in`post'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:82:in `update'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:102:in`add'/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:283:in `adapt_response'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:190:in`execute'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:176:in `send_and_receive'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in`block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in`send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
(eval):2:in `post'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:82:in`update'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:102:in `add'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:107:in`add_documents'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:30:in `add'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/session.rb:91:in`index'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `index'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/retry_5xx_session_proxy.rb:17:in`method_missing'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `index'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot-2.1.1/lib/sunspot.rb:184:in`index'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:257:in `block (2 levels) in solr_index'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:360:in`solr_benchmark'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:256:in `block in solr_index'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:75:in`find_in_batches'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3/lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/relation.rb:70:in `find_in_batches'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:254:in`solr_index'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:203:in `solr_reindex'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:57:in`block (4 levels) in '
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/class_set.rb:16:in `each'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/class_set.rb:16:in`each'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:68:in`with_session'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in`call'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in`each'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in`block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in`invoke_task'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in`each'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in`run_with_threads'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in`block in run'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in`run'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rake:23:in`load'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`eval'
/home/shruthi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => sunspot:reindex`

Comment: Can we have the full error please? Will help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended from ticket [solr, sunspot, bad request, illegal character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375336/solr-sunspot-bad-request-illegal-character) I created config/initializers/sunspot.rb with the suggested code and it did the trick.

Here's the issue mentioned in that ticket where the code was first suggested.
https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/570